# Facebook web app on XAMPP localhost - how to go through the review?

Tags: facebook, permissions, xampp, localhost, photos

I am currently trying to develop a simple Facebook web application on **XAMPP** localhost to read photos and tags.

I understand one does not need to go through Login Review if the app requests the three basic permissions: public_profile, user_friends, email

I would need to ask for **user_photos** permission, and a review is needed.

But it is hosted on my **localhost on XAMPP**. Thus of course Facebook review is not able to access it.

Do I need to host it online somewhere or is there another way?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are the only one using that app, then you don’t need review. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#apps-all-users-are-developers

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but I would want to extend the app to other users to use.

Comment: Well those other users will hardly be using it on your localhost, I assume? So you will have to put it on the web somewhere anyway, no?

Comment: It's a web application intended to run on localhost on just one computer. It can right now only retrieve pictures for the developer's own account. I would like it such that other Facebook users who logs in would also have their photos shown. Hence I need the user_photos permission. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to host it so that they can access and check for the review process. Hosting in your local server won't help. Try something like Amazon services/Digital Ocean which helped me to get it reviewed for publish_actions permission.

Review Guidelines are below from Facebook

[Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I would try Amazon services/Digital Ocean.